# Combining multiprocessing with gevent

Tags: multiprocessing, gevent, coroutine

If I use a multiprocessing pipe to pass data to a second process, and that second process uses a gevent pool to perform network operations, could I safely allow any of those green-threads to read from the pipe as long as a I use a gevent semaphore to control access?

I'd use *gipc*, but I prefer to be able to have the shared-data facilities of MP.

Answer (score 0):

short answer.. yes that should work!